# Change recordsource but keep filter

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba

I have a small problem:

My form has 2 possible underling queries (with exactly the same fields and metadata) being changed from one to another when needed by the user.
 The problem is, that after changing the record source access doesn´t keep the filter apllied before.

I change the recordsource OnLoad and there schould be a filter according to macro, what opened the form. The filter doesnt work.

Can somebody give me a hint with this?

Answer (score 0):

You mention a filter according to the macro, but you do not say what the macro is. let us say you have:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "form1", , , "atext='def'"
```

This will set the Filter property of the form to:

```
atext='def'
```

You can save the filter property before changing the recordsource and reapply it.

```
sFilter = Me.Filter
Me.RecordSource = "select * from table1"
Me.Filter = sFilter
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It is not so hard to make it work.
You have to change the recordsource onLoad and the form is opened by a macro with a "where" condition then:
 1. Put a condition into onLoad method whether the filter is on.
 2. If True then save the Filter as a string and save a True as bool
 3. make the recordSource changing
 4. control your bool, whether it is true
 5. If True then set the filter back
 6. Turn filter on

```
Private Sub ChengeRecS()
Dim fltr As String
Dim fB As Boolean
If Me.FilterOn = True Then
    fB = True
    fltr = Me.Filter
End If
Me.RecordSource = "newRecordSource"
If fB = True Then
    Me.Filter = fltr
    Me.FilterOn = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, just like I said, except with unnecessary extra bits.